# Why is $\{ x\} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am confused how the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$ , $B(\mathbb{R}^n)$, holds every $\{ x \}$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

The proof in Klenke's *Probability Theory* goes like this:

Given that $(\mathbb{R}^n, \tau)$ is a topological space, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the $\sigma$-algebra that is generated by the open sets of $\tau$.
So, if $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a closed set, then $C ^c \in \tau$ is also in $B(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and hence $C$ is a Borel set, since $B$ is closed under complements. --(jump)--> In particular, this implies that {$ x$} $\in B(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I do not understand how he is making this jump.

Going from top to bottom: If $C$ is a closet set, which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then yes, the complement of $C$, which is $C^c$ by definition is in the topology $\tau$. Since $B$ is closed under complements, $C$ is a part of $B$. I do not see how this necessitates $C$ = {$x$}. What if the singleton set {$x$} is not a part of $B$? How do I prove this contradiction?

Comment: Every closed set belongs to the Borel sigma algebra. Singletons are closed in $\mathbb{R^n}$, and so in particular they are Borel sets.

Comment: Can you see that $\{x\}$ is closed in the usual topology?

Comment: @Mark, thank you for your response. But how are singleton's closed under $R^n$? What necessitates the complement of a singleton to be in the topology?

Comment: @BrianMoehring, thank you for taking the time to respond! I don't, unfortunately...

Comment: @megamence Well, try to show that $\mathbb{R^n}\setminus\{x\}$ is open. Given any $y\in\mathbb{R^n}\setminus\{x\}$ you need to find an open ball around $y$ which doesn't contain the point $x$.

Comment: Okay... if I gave you a second point $y \neq x$, can you find an open set $U$ such that $y \in U$ but $x \not\in U$?

Comment: The answer to your question depends somewhat on how you define the usual topology.  Using the metric definition, a set $U$ is *open* if every point in $U$ is contained in a ball which is contained in $U$, and a set $K$ is closed if its complement is open.  Take $U = \mathbb{R}^n$, set fix a point $y \in U$, and let $r = d(x,y)/2$.  The ball $B(y,r)$ is contained in $U$, and $y$ is arbitrary, hence $U$ is open.  The complement of $U$, $\{x\}$, is therefore closed.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, after seeing the term "usual" topology in the comment, I realized I wasn't reading closely enough. All good now!

Comment: You might be interested in the following paper, which is freely available on the internet: [*When is a point Borel?*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-80/issue-1/When-is-a-point-Borel/pjm/1102785960.full) by Harley/McNulty (1979), especially p. 155.

Answer (score 4):

We are assuming $\tau$ is the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then for any singleton $x$, you should show that the set $U = \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ x \}$ is open, hence in the Borel sets. Then the complement $U^c = \{ x \}$ is in the Borel sets since it is closed under complements

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that I completely missed Klenke's portion of the "usual" class of open sets defined by the metric. Applying the definition of the usual metric,

$$\tau = \left\{ \bigcup _{(x,r)\in F} B_r (x): F\subset \Omega \times (0,\infty) \right\}$$

Where $B_r(y)$ is the set of all points that are within a distance $r$ of $y$. Setting $r$ to be $d(x,y)/2$ and performing a union, we see that $x$ is never present inside the unions. The complement of that set is the singleton $\{ x\}$.